# Setting Actor To Listen For Button Click In LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, listener, textfield

**Background Information:** I am currently working in a Dialog class I have extended for my game. Inside of this dialog's content table I have both an Image and a Table (lets call it `ioTable`). Inside of `ioTable` I have a combination of both Labels and TextFields. The idea is that the dialog becomes a sort of form for the use to fill out.

Next, inside of the Dialog's button table, I want to include a "Clear" TextButton (`clearButton`). The idea that `clearButton` will clear any values written to the TextFields of `ioTable`.

**My Question:** Is is possible to add a listener to each of the TextFields of `ioTable` that will trigger when `clearButton` is pressed. As always, any other creative solution is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just give the EventListener a reference to the table you want to clear:

```
// Assuming getSkin() and ioTable are defined elsewhere and ioTable is final
TextButton clearButton = new TextButton("Clear", getSkin());
clearButton.addListener(new EventListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean handle(Event event) {
    for(Actor potentialField : table.getChildren()) {
      if(potentialField instanceof TextField) {
        ((TextField)potentialField).setText("");
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
});
// Add clearButton to your dialog
```

If you see yourself creating multiple clearButtons, you could easily wrap this in a helper method or extend `TextButton`.

Comment: Perfect! The instanceof operator completely escaped me, thank you!